# How to group the values in parameter using filter?

Tags: parameters, tableau-desktop

I have the city_group field and respective cities in the parameter. Now I want a specific city_group related cities in the filter.

For example, I have 5 city_groups. I tried to create a 1 calculation field for each city group and 5 city parameters using Case. I am unable to keep all of the parameters in one calculation.